# jsonschema2pojo not generating class

Tags: android, retrofit2

With the json response I am not getting the jsonschema2pojo class.
I am getting error like this "There's a problem: Unexpected character ('r' (code 114)): was expecting double-quote to start field name (line 2, column 2)".
I am newer in retrofit.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: response_text: [
{
counterId: 1,
counterName: "NA",
narration: "",
extraDate: "/Date(1399523916903)/",
extra1: "",
extra2: ""
}] The json response i am getting.

Comment: please call api from postman and than after copy that response into JSONSCHEMA2POJO site

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution that you need to put "" to all of your response parameter.